# Install mysql 8 along with mysql 5.7 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there any way to install MySQL 8 along with the already installed MySQL 5.7? I want to run two instances, one for version 8 and one for version 5.7. I have tried this on Windows, it's effortless, but I cannot understand how I achieve this on the Linux system (Ubuntu 22.04).

Help is appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: You can do this if you use Docker containers or another sort of virtualisation. Otherwise, you are in for a world of hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using docker. I followed this article:

https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/setup-multiple-mysql-servers-with-different-versions-docker-du107solq

- Install docker  `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`
- Install mysql with docker `sudo docker run --name mysql-57-container -p 127.0.0.1:3310:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword -d mysql:5.7`

Here one thing is to notice, you will have use a flag `--restart=always`, this flag restarts the docker container on machine bootup

Docker will download the intended image from the mysql library and after a while, you test out your installtion with following command:

`mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3310`